# is there any PHP editor like visualstudio which have GUI IDE Components like buttons, gridview and more

Tags: php

is there any PHP editor like visualstudio which have GUI IDE Components like buttons, gridview and more..

Comment: Are you trying to write desktop software with PHP? Or were you hoping for an IDE that generates UI components in HTML for the web, and connects them to PHP code automatically somehow?

Comment: ya i wanna create websites as visual studio do

Comment: Your HTML will really suck if you use an IDE to create it. Go and learn HTML. Write the HTML yourself and use one of the JavaScript framework providing you the widgets you need.. jQuery UI or ExtJS would be candidates for that.

Answer (score 2):

Adobe Dreamweaver !

http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/whatisdreamweaver/

Comment: +1 for this answer. if you're going to use anything for this, then Dreamweaver is the answer. However, I agree wth @ThiefMaster's comment that you will end up producing poor quality code if you go down this path. (and that applies to Visual Studio as well)

Comment: @Spudley Visual Studio also? You mean it is bad using Visual Studio? So what is the laternative?

Comment: @DamithRuwan - please bear in mind that my comment was written six and a half years ago. Visual Studio is a very different product today to what it was then. Back then, the toolchain around VS was very heavily tied to Microsoft dev platforms, and didn't really offer much to a PHP developer. It is better these days. However, I would still suggest going with PHP Storm or NetBeans as an IDE for PHP rather than VS. VS is better, but it still has a lot of baggage.

Comment: @Spudley Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

[RealStudio Web Edition](http://www.realsoftware.com/web/)

Answer (score 0):

[CodeCharge Studio](http://www.yessoftware.com/products/product_detail.php?product_id=1) sounds like what you're interested in. But, it's nowhere near as polished as VS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid if you want to create websites as Visual Studio does, your only option is Visual Studio, there is a huge amount of support code etc that is generated to run an asp.net site and Microsoft has gone to a lot of work to make it as polished as possible.  Trying to do it with PHP and another IDE will lead to heartache.  My suggestion is to move to Visual Studio if possible, or re-examine how you intend to create your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP designer or Dreamweaver these software provides the drag and drop functionality. You can try any.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Nusphere PhpEd IDE for PHP development: http://www.nusphere.com

Answer (score 0):

Codecharge Studio 5 is what you are looking for. His best advance is the code generation and direct Artisteer's templates support. It is just like Visual Studio as you can create php events or javascript events easily with a click of a button. There is also a CMS based on Codecharge Studio and you can download it for free at www.krisonav.com which supports most of the functions that every contemporary CMS includes.

Comment: Are you affiliated with the product you're promoting here? You've posted two similar answers in a very short time frame, and both sound pretty promotional. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers